# The type or namespace name could not be found , but only when building via github actions

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, blazor, github-actions, blazor-server-side

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC app that uses a bit of Blazor Server. My root Blazor component is defined in a separate assembly which I am referencing as a project reference. I am adding the component to a razor page with the component tag helper.

```
@using NamespaceOfReferencedAssembly
<component type="typeof(MyRootRouterComponent)" render-mode="Server" />
```

Everything works fine locally, but when I attempt to publish my app to Azure through github actions, I get the following error during the build pipeline

> The type or namespace name 'MyRootRouterComponent' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I can build in Release mode locally. I am also able to publish to Azure using Zip Deploy without any issue.

I did not make any changes to the default workflow file, but here it is.

```
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App - myappnane

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: '6.0.x'
          include-prerelease: true

      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release 

      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: .net-app

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'My app name'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_REDACTED }}
          package: .
```

Here is the csproj of my server app

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>REDACTED</UserSecretsId>
    <WebProject_DirectoryAccessLevelKey>0</WebProject_DirectoryAccessLevelKey>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <Optimize>True</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="6.0.6" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.6" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="6.0.6" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.6">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.6">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.25.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="1.25.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" Version="4.7.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MY_REFERENCED_PROJECT.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And here is the csproj of my referenced component library

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <SupportedPlatform Include="browser" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web" Version="6.0.6" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" Version="4.7.4">
          <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
          <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I suspect that something in the build is wrongfully trimming unused code, but I have not been able to find any configuration options that will make it work.

Comment: Are you using an Ubuntu machine locally? Or Win10, 11?

Comment: Also please share the .csproj file in github.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the csproj files.

Locally I am using Windows, not Ubuntu, but I am able to deploy from Visual Studio to the Ubuntu machine using Zip Deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by changing the build job to run on Windows.

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
```